Provision certificates fails in Graylog preflight UI
I installed Graylog DataNode following these instructions:
https://go2docs.graylog.org/current/downloading_and_installing_graylog/install_graylog_data_node.htm?tocpath=Installing%20Graylog%7C_____3
I hope I did not miss anything. I am trying to use Graylog Preflight UI to do the initial setup. However, when pressing "Provision certificate and continue" ultimately I get "failed to connect to datanode".
I noticed that it tries to connect to port 9200. Whereas datanode is listening on port 8999? Do I overlook something?
systemctl status graylog-datanode shows graylog-datanode is running.
netstat -tulpn does not show anything listening on port 9200. Only the graylog-server (Java-based webserver) on port 9000 and graylog-datanode on port 8999.
From "tail -f datanode.log":
2024-09-17T11:58:08.664Z WARN  [OpensearchNodeHeartbeat] Opensearch REST api of process 20414 unavailable. Cause: Connection refused
2024-09-17T11:58:09.888Z INFO  [NetworkListener] Started listener bound to [68.183.117.210:8999]
2024-09-17T11:58:09.907Z INFO  [HttpServer] [HttpServer] Started.
2024-09-17T11:58:09.920Z INFO  [JerseyService] Started REST API at <68.183.117.210:8999>


Interesting I am seeing the same:
2024-11-21T15:53:21.627Z INFO  [NetworkListener] Started listener bound to [0.0.0.0:8999]
2024-11-21T15:53:21.627Z INFO  [HttpServer] [HttpServer-2] Started.
2024-11-21T15:53:21.627Z INFO  [JerseyService] Started REST API at <0.0.0.0:8999>

https://eros:9200 – eros
